# jquery waiting for one function to run before another starts

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function set up like so:

```
function sixth_screen_intro() {
    current_slide = 7;
    fifth_screen_outro();

    $("#voting-txt").animate({
        top: "50%",
        marginTop:-80
    },500);
}
```

here is the fifth_screen_outro() for reference, but as a note I'd like to keep them separate:

```
function fifth_screen_outro() {
    $("#budget-txt").animate({
        left:600
    },500);
    coin_hop();
    $("#piggy_bank").animate({
        marginTop:-190,
        left:50
    },70, function() {
        $("#piggy_bank").animate({
            marginTop:-141,
            left:0
        },70, function () {
            coin_hop_delay();
            $("#piggy_bank").delay(400).animate({
                marginTop:-190,
                left:-50
            },70, function () {
                $("#piggy_bank").animate({
                    marginTop:-141,
                    left:-100
                },70, function () {
                    coin_hop_delay();
                    $("#piggy_bank").delay(400).animate({
                        marginTop:-190,
                        left:-150
                    },70, function () {
                        $("#piggy_bank").animate({
                            marginTop:-141,
                            left:-200
                        },70, function () {
                            coin_hop_delay();
                            $("#piggy_bank").delay(400).animate({
                                marginTop:-190,
                                left:-250
                            },70, function () {
                                $("#piggy_bank").animate({
                                    marginTop:-141,
                                    left:-300
                                },70, function () {
                                    coin_hop_delay();
                                    $("#piggy_bank").delay(400).animate({
                                        marginTop:-190,
                                        left:-350
                                    },70, function () {
                                        $("#piggy_bank").animate({
                                            marginTop:-141,
                                            left:-400
                                        },70);
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

the sixth_screen_intro() gets called with a simple on click.  Is there way to make the voting-txt animation not play, until the fifth_screen_outro() has finished executing?  Some sort of callback perhaps?

Comment: There probably is, but you'll have to post the `fifth_screen_outro` function as well.

Comment: so it's actually just an animation, but it's quite a long animation, so instead of putting the whole function in there I made it it's function.  But it's just a bunch of the same type of animating that the voting-txt is

Comment: You'll need to hook into the callback or deferred return from those animations, and figure out when they are done to be able to wait for them.

Comment: I just posted that function.  So how would you go about doing that, I wasn't able to figure that out

Comment: **This looks like a bad design concept**.

Comment: I think it's the only way to do web animations that are compatible with IE 8, but if you had any suggestions I'd love to hear them.  Just saying it looks bad doesn't help me fix anything...

Comment: holy-callback-hell. Use Deferreds to make that not so painful to write/read/maintain

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the nested stuff, and use a function you can call instead :

```
function fifth_screen_outro(callback) {
    var i = 0, l = 0;

    $("#budget-txt").animate({
        left:600
    },500);
    coin_hop();
    ani(-141, 10);

    function ani(val, times) {
        var s = val == -190;
        if (s) coin_hop_delay();
        $("#piggy_bank").delay(s ? 400 : 0).animate({
            marginTop: val,
            left: l
        },70, function() {
            if (i >= times) {
                callback();
            }else{
                l += 50;
                i++;
                ani(s ? -141 : -190, times);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xRXP3/1/)

Comment: I don't know?  It's an animation of a piggy bank bounce/hopping across the screen.  It needs to work in IE8 and this was the only way I could think to do it.  What are other possible methods of web animation besides this and css3?

Answer (score 0):

you can use timeout function so that $("#voting-txt").animate gets called after some time or u can use on complete of jquery to achieve this.

timeout is simple and will solve your problem

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#voting-txt").animate(){}
    }, 1000);
```

If your first() function is doing something asynchronously (such as making an Ajax request) then you'll want to make second() the callback for that asynchronous request, rather than having it execute immediately after first() returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `deferred`:

```
function sixth_screen_intro() {
    current_slide = 7;
    fifth_screen_outro().done(function() {
        $("#voting-txt").animate({
            top: "50%",
            marginTop:-80
        },500);
    });
}

function fifth_screen_outro() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $("#budget-txt").animate({
        left:600
    },500);
    coin_hop();
    $("#piggy_bank").animate({
        marginTop:-190,
        left:50
    //...
                                    },70, function () {
                                        $("#piggy_bank").animate({
                                            marginTop:-141,
                                            left:-400
                                        },70, function() {
                                           def.resolve(true);
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: hmm, this looks interesting, how exactly does it work?  What's def.resolve(true); and what's var def = $.Deferred();

Comment: See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/). A `deferred` is basically an object that will be resolved as complete or failed at some point in the future. It's a way to asynchronously notify other functions of completion.

Comment: cool, I'll have to do some reading, one last question, what does the $. at the start of $.Deferred do?  is that a different way of writing $(?

Comment: Some jQuery functions are not called on a selected object, but on the `jQuery` object itself, like `$.ajax` or one form of `$.each`. Writing `$.Deferred()` returns a new `deferred` object instance.